# TLS and Packet Filtering

Tags: pf, tls

I want to set up a client wit BSD packet filtering that only allows outgoing 443 connections.  Would this do the trick in my `pf.conf`?

```
block out
block in
pass out on eth0 inet proto tcp from (eth0) to any port 443 keep state
```

Is there any reason to allow incoming connections on 443 if the server is always on the "outside"?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't allow incoming connections to port :443, on other distributions I've used `/usr/sbin/iptables rules-to-allow-only-ougoing-on-port-:443`.  Only allow incoming connection if you're client requires that otherwise I wouldn't bother with it.

Keep in mind that allowing necessary incoming ports exposes security breach especially if the server is always outside. I've been hacked in the past where I had to rebuild the server due to open ports and had to run several vulnerability tools in order to get the servers secured.